# Track some emails with gmail gem

Tags: ruby, gmail, tracking

I'm using gmail gem to send emails and I need track these emails. How can I do this?

I'm trying search the email with the message_id, but it bring all emails from my inbox and I want just the responses of a specific email.

Here is my actual code:

*save email with the message_id*

```
mail = gmail.deliver(email)
Email.create(:message_id => mail.message_id, :from => user.email,
  :to => annotation.to, :body => annotation.content, :title => annotation.title,
  :annotation => annotation, :user => user)
```

*search the mails with message_id*

```
messages = gmail.inbox.mails(:message_id => email.message_id)
```

Regards,

Fabrício Ferrari de Campos

Comment: Which gmail gem are you using? Link to repo would help.

Answer (score 3):

you can take [Net::IMAP](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/Net/IMAP.html) a look.

```
uid =  gmail.conn.uid_search(["HEADER", "Message-ID", "<324820.440351247482145930.JavaMail.coremail@bj163app31.163.com>"])[0]
#=> 103
message = Gmail::Message.new(gmail.inbox, uid)
#=>  #<Gmail::Message0x12a72e798 mailbox=INBOX uid=103> 
message.subject
#=> "hello world"
message.message_id
#=> "<324820.440351247482145930.JavaMail.coremail@bj163app31.163.com>"
```

have not find a method can search by message_id.via this way you can get a specific email.

Answer (score 3):

Using the standard gmail gem, this seems to work quite well

```
messages = gmail.inbox.mails(:query => ['HEADER', 'Message-ID', email.message_id])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using [this Gmail Gem](https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail) (not sure if that's the same gem you're using).

The Message ID header is part of the email object that is generated. It is then searchable using `rfc822msgid` (described in [Gmail's Advanced Search help page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)).

Here's an example:

```
def gmail_connect
  Gmail.connect(email_address, password)
end

def send_email
  gmail = gmail_connect
  email = gmail.compose do
    to recipient@mail.internet
    subject 'Hello'
    content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
    body 'Hello, World'
  end

  gmail.deliver(email)
  gmail.logout
  email.message_id
end

def verify_sent_email(id)
  gmail = gmail_connect
  found = gmail.mailbox('sent').find(rfc822msgid: id).count
  gmail.logout
  ( found > 0 ) ? true : false
end

id = send_email
verify_sent_email(id)
```